# Spring-boot serving content outside context root and getting content as resources

Tags: spring, resources, spring-boot

I've added new resources handler "outside context root" with following ConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicAssetsConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/dynamicassets/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("file:/var/dynamicassets/");
         super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```

Handler works fine when making requests to server, but I would like to access the content of the "/dynamicassets/**" as resources. Like I can access "static assets" (assets directory inside context root):

```
@Inject
private WebApplicationContext webContext;


public Resource[] getStaticAssetResources() {
  // returns array of ServletResource objects
  return webContext.getResources( "/assets/*.*");
}

public Resource[] getDynamicAssetResources() {
  // this fails to get resources, because 
  // dynamicassets not found from context 
  return webContext.getResources( "/dynamicassets/*.*");
}
```

How could I access files in "/dynamicassets/" as ServletResource objects ?